# How to enforce order http requests on a list of observables in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular7

I need to get a list of Id's ids => this.getIds() and get their names 
 => getNames(id) for each id in the list of ids using mergeMap().
Can someone please check what I'm doing wrong below (it fails to compile)?

in, myservice.ts:

```
getIds()<any> {
     this.http
        .post(url1, '')
        .subscribe(map(({ Ids }: any) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id, Name: item.Name }))));
    }
getNames():Observable<any[]> {
     return this.http
        .post(url2, '')
        .pipe(map(({ Names }: any) => Names.map(item => ({Sid: item.Id, Name: item.Name }))));
}
```

in, component.ts:

```
  getIds(): void {
  this.myservice
     .getIds.pipe(
     mergeMap(id => this.getNames(id)),
     mergeMap(names => names),
     toArray()
     )
  }
getNames(): void {
   this.myservice
     .getNames(ids)
     .subscribe(val => this.data = val);
  }
```

Comment: What is the error message you get during compilation?

Comment: the line 44 is the last line in the file.
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (44:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| });

Comment: In which file? And which line is it in the code snippets you've added?

Comment: sorry; it's the myservice.ts. the last line is the end of the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning anything from `getNames` method of component, which should ideally return an `Observable`

```
getNames(): void {
   return this.myservice
      .getNames(ids)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the signature of your getIds function from:

```
getIds()<any>
```

to

```
getIds(): any
```

Comment: With this change, I get the following:
    ERROR in idtable.component.ts(128,20): error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type '() => any'.
    idtable.component.ts(129,34): error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ids'.

Comment: Oh sorry in that case change it to `getIds: Observable<any>`

Comment: The issue left is with the line `mergeMap(names => names),`
The compile error is, 
` 70% building modules 676/676 modules 0 activeERROR in src/app/mcomponent.ts(132,19): error TS2345: Argument of type '(names: {}) => {}' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{}>'.
      Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '{}'.`